# Force one specific language across the whole Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

I need to configure my Ruby on Rails app to use one single language (English).

By default, Rails translates all form validation messages to the local language.

I have tried adding the folowing to the file `config/application.rb`:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
config.i18n.available_locales = [:en]
```

When I run my form (which is generated with a form generator), the validation messages appear in my local language (Spanish) instead of English.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you set `I18n.locale =` somewhere in your application?

Comment: No, I don't know where to set it. I am using Rails 6.

Comment: I suggest reading about [I18n in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Comment: Tried  ```config.i18n.default_locale = :en``` in the same file and didn´t work either. I have read the guide, but still can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you have `config.i18n.fallbacks` configured somewhere?